# Microsoft keyboard media keys on OS X without Microsoft's Drivers

Tags: macos, drivers, keyboard

Is there any way I can enable at least the media keys (play/pause and volume) from my Microsoft keyboard on OS X Snow Leopard?

They used to work perfectly on Leopard using Microsoft's IntelliType, but on Snow Leopard - although Microsoft says it is compatible - I get random kernel panics whenever it is installed, so I just can't use it.

Comment: Hear hear!! I've finally given up on the latest IntelliType drivers and went back to my Macally bluetooth keyboard. They caused 3 panics already today.

Answer (score 1):

Which keyboard are you using? Apparently the media keys are considered a standard part of the USB HID spec, so they should 'just work'. I'm using a Wireless Comfort Keyboard 5000, which uses a 2.4Ghz connection to a USB dongle. For most keys everything works as expected, but the Windows key is mapped to the Command key, so it's in the wrong place for a Mac. A friend of mine pointed me to [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) which seems to be very stable on Snow Leopard so far. Another possibility is [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/), which should let you assign functions to the non-standard keys. I haven't tried that yet with the dedicated keys on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but you can use [QuickSilver](https://github.com/tiennou/blacktree-alchemy/downloads) to create global hotkey mappings to iTunes. For example, I have <kbd>CTRL+⌘+K</kbd> setup to Play/Pause iTunes, no matter what application is active.